# Displaying TextField When ComboBox is Changed

Tags: java, swing, combobox, textfield

I am in the process of creating a program that calculates the area of certain shapes. When I run the program, selecta a shape and enter the values for the area, it calculates the area properly for all shapes. However, if I wanted to calculate the area for another shape without closing the program, it just adds on the boxes after the previous shape instead of switching them. I was wondering if there was a way to get it only display one set of textfields when you change shapes? My code is below:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

JComboBox shapeList;

JTextField answer;
JTextField shapeSelected;
JTextField circle;
JTextField square;
JTextField triangle;
JTextField triangle3;

JLabel circle2;
JLabel square2;
JLabel triangle2;
JLabel triangle4;
JLabel triangle5;
JLabel squareAnswer;
JLabel circleAnswer;
JLabel triangleAnswer;

JButton compute;

MainPanel()
{
    String [] shapes = {"circle", "square", "triangle"};

    shapeList = new JComboBox(shapes);
    shapeList.addActionListener(this);
    add(shapeList);

    compute = new JButton("Compute");
    compute.addActionListener(this);
    add(compute);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    Object o = e.getSource();

    if (o == shapeList)
    {   
        if (shapeList.getSelectedItem().equals("circle")) 
        {
            circle2 = new JLabel();
            circle2.setText("Radius:");
            add(circle2);

            circle = new JTextField(10);
            add(circle);

            this.revalidate();
            this.repaint();     
        }

        if (shapeList.getSelectedItem().equals("square")) 
        {
            square2 = new JLabel();
            square2.setText("Width/Height:");
            add(square2);

            square = new JTextField(10);
            add(square);

            this.revalidate();
            this.repaint();
        }

        if (shapeList.getSelectedItem().equals("triangle")) 
        {
            triangle4 = new JLabel();
            triangle4.setText("Base:");
            add(triangle4);

            triangle = new JTextField(10);
            add(triangle);

            triangle5 = new JLabel();
            triangle5.setText("Height:");
            add(triangle5);

            triangle3 = new JTextField(10);
            add(triangle3);

            this.revalidate();
            this.repaint();
        }
    }

    if (o == compute)
    {
        if (shapeList.getSelectedItem().equals("square"))
        {
            squareAnswer = new JLabel();
            squareAnswer.setText("Area:");
            add(squareAnswer);

            answer = new JTextField(10);
            add(answer);

            this.revalidate();
            this.repaint();

            double sum = Double.parseDouble(square.getText()) * Double.parseDouble(square.getText());
            answer.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        }

        if (shapeList.getSelectedItem().equals("triangle"))
        {
            triangleAnswer = new JLabel();
            triangleAnswer.setText("Area:");
            add(triangleAnswer);

            answer = new JTextField(10);
            add(answer);

            this.revalidate();
            this.repaint();

            double sum = (Double.parseDouble(triangle.getText()) * Double.parseDouble(triangle3.getText())) / 2;
            answer.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        }

        if (shapeList.getSelectedItem().equals("circle"))
        {
            circleAnswer = new JLabel();
            circleAnswer.setText("Area:");
            add(circleAnswer);

            answer = new JTextField(10);
            add(answer);

            this.revalidate();
            this.repaint();

            double sum = (Double.parseDouble(circle.getText()) * Double.parseDouble(circle.getText())) * Math.PI;
            answer.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CardLayout`. When you select the shape from the combo box you swap panels for the specified shape.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

The working examples shows how to sway panels when an item is selected in the combo box.

Comment: [Please note](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42916940/hiding-text-fields-with-setvisible)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, thanks. That is frustrating. The exact same question posted 3 times in two days without any effort made to implement suggestions that have been made.